# install script doesn't appear to run but shows in database

Tags: magento

I am following this [tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) from Alan Storm and am struggling with the setup part of the instructions.

My config file: app/code/local/Alan/Storm/etc/config.xml

```
    <modules>
      <Alan_Storm>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
      </Alan_Storm>
    </modules>
        <resources>
          <storm_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Alan_Storm</module>
                <class>Alan_Storm_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
          </storm_setup>
        </resources>
```

I have also put the required code into app/code/local/Alan/Storm/sql/storm_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
echo 'Running this upgrade: ' . get_class($this) . "\n <br /> \n";
die("Exit for now");
```

The tutorial states that when loading a page the above file will run and display the echo command on the screen. This does not happen. I have looked in my database and have found storm_setup, so it has successfully ran, but can someone explain why I had no output on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. For others struggling with this problem.

It seems that I must have run the script prior to putting the echo and die commands in place.  Magento will only run your install script if it is not in the database, so by deleting the required row from within the database and running the script again you should get the expected results.